# Making gridlines using python to fix cylinder in Blender

Tags: python, modeling, mesh

I am working on a project where I have to make gridlines at different angles and at each node, I have to place a cylinder. Since the number of cylinder to be placed is more than 2,40,000, I am searching for a way to code this using python for faster execution.

Comment: Do the cylinders represent the nodes or the edges between nodes.  One mesh or multiple objects, curves perhaps?  What data is being used? Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/109284/edit) with more details to clarify.

Comment: If your grid can be wrangled into a single mesh, and your cylinders don't mind being identical, you might want to look into [Dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html),